# Check If a method Has Been Called and Do Not Call It Again

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In `touchesBegan` I call a method `[self animateWindow];` when I touch a `UILabel`. It animates and brings the window from top. When I touch that `UILabel` again, I don't want that method `[self animateWindow];` to be called again because it animates and brings the window again which is already being displayed. How do I do this? Any help? I tried searching all over, couldn't find the exact answer.

Comment: You could check the current state before/or during your function call?

Comment: Is this C++, Objective-C or Objective-C++? Please re-tag it if appropriate.

Comment: Objective-C Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3):

Just create an instance variable which is a BOOL as use it as a flag:

```
@property (assign, monatomic) BOOL hasAnimated;

- (void) touchesBegan...
{
    if (!self.hasAnimated) {
        [self animateWindow];
        self.hasAnimated = YES;
    }
}
```

Based on your expanded description in the comments, you're going to need to add some more logic which checks which label is actually being touch. A better solution may be to use gesture recognisers on each of the labels. Then you have direct access to the view of the gesture recognizer to check which label it was (perhaps using the `tag`) and you can add and remove gestures depending on what state you're in (only some labels should respond to touches and they should show or hide).

Comment: in viewDidLoad should i make the BOOL hasAnimated = FALSE; ?

Comment: Yes.  State 'hasAnimated = FALSE;' inside your viewDidLoad.

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't bring up the window at all now. The problem is I'm having like 5+ labels. When I touch a single label, I want the window to animate and drop down, if the window is already down, I dont want that function to be called i.e no animation and dropping down. When i click something else other than label, i want the dropdown window to animate and go up again.

Comment: Technically you should set it to NO (not false), and it should default to a value of NO.

Comment: Even adding gesture recognizer, the same problem still holds up. For example if (touch.view.tag >=1 && touch.view.tag<=5) { [self animateWindow]; } else { [self animateWindowBack]; } So now,every time I touch a label the animateWindow comes down. Even if it is already down.